# set the position of list element to another when using click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, offset

I am creating a simple contact app. I have 2 lists for name and information, both which have information inserted into it from an array of objects. 1 list is for names, and the other is for number etc.. When I click on a name the 2nd list displays more information about the person in a box. I am trying to set the position of the box to correspond with the name I clicked.

I thought of using offset() but I am not sure if I implemented it correctly, here is my code,

```
    function displaysingle(contactid) {
        var Email = contactarray[contactid].email;
        var Number = contactarray[contactid].number;
        var Address = contactarray[contactid].address;

        $('#contactinfo').append('<li class="single"><a id="link">' + Email+'</a><br><br>' + Number + '<br><br>' + Address + '</li>')
    }

//click event handler to display user information if user is clicked
    $('.itemname').on('click', function(event) {


        for (i in contactarray)
            if ($(event.target).html() === contactarray[i].name) {  

                $('.single').offset(this);

                $(".itemname").css("background-color", "inherit");
                $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(79,79,79");

                contactid = i
                $('#contactinfo').empty();
                displaysingle(contactid);
            }
```

To have a better understanding, please look at my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8pbLvtjf/2/

Answer (score 2):

you can set the top position of the name you clicked and then apply it to the class `.single` value and allow it to go on the same level. I have edited the `CSS` a little bit as well.

working jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/joshstevens19/8pbLvtjf/7/

working example which runs on SO below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function ContactItem (name, email, number,address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.number = number;
        this.address = '6539 Wilton Ave' + '<br>' + 'Culver City CA 90234';
    }
//new object instances of constructor intalized in array of objects
    var contactarray = [
        new ContactItem('Christian', 'christian@yahoo.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Rich', 'rich@tripod.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Scott', 'scott@mailinator.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Danny', 'danny@hotmail.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Taka', 'taka@myspace.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Tim', 'tim@netscape.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Patrick', 'patrick@live.com', '323-555-124'),
        new ContactItem('Jacques', 'jacques@aol.com', '323-555-124')
    ];
//function to print out names into list
    function displayName() {
        for (i = 0; i < contactarray.length; i++) {
            $('#contacts').append('<li class="itemname"><a href="#">' + contactarray[i].name + '</a></li>');
        }
    }
//function to print other information based on option choice 
    function displayinfo () {
        $('#contactinfo').empty(); //empties the list 
        for (i = 0; i < contactarray.length; i++) {
            $('#contactinfo').append('<li class="itemname">' + contactarray[i][$('#dropdown').val()] + '</li>');
            $(".itemname").css("background-color", "inherit");
        } //uses the value of #dropdown that matches object property 
    }
//function that contains full user information
    function displaysingle(contactid) {
        var Email = contactarray[contactid].email;
        var Number = contactarray[contactid].number;
        var Address = contactarray[contactid].address;
        
        $('#contactinfo').append('<li class="single"><a id="link">' + Email+'</a><br><br>' + Number + '<br><br>' + Address + '</li>')
    }
    
    displayName();
    displayinfo();
    $('#dropdown').change(displayinfo); //calls function again if there is a change to #dropdown
    
//click event handler to display user information if user is clicked
    $('.itemname').on('click', function(event) {


        for (i in contactarray)
            if ($(event.target).html() === contactarray[i].name) {  

                $('.single').offset(this);

                $(".itemname").css("background-color", "inherit");
                $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(79,79,79");

                contactid = i
                $('#contactinfo').empty();
                //set top and left position of popup
                $("#contactinfo").css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY});
                displaysingle(contactid);
            }
    });
})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    src: url('../fonts/myriad-pro/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
}

body {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular', sans-serif, serif;
}

/*------------------MAIN----------------------*/


@media (min-width: 20em) {
    main {
        width: 87.5%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #acacac;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px black;
    }

    #top {
        height: 12.5%;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(62,62,62,1) 2%,rgba(50,50,50,1) 50%,rgba(37,37,37,1) 100%);
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

    h4 {
        color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
        padding: 8% 0 0 6.4%;
    }
    
/*------------------MID----------------*/
    #mid {  
        height: 76.2%;
        background-color: rgb(33,33,33);
    }

    #contacts {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-image: url('../bullet.png');
        margin-left: 10%;
        width: 30%;
    }

    #contactinfo {
        display: inline-block;
        color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
        margin-left: -1.9%;
        width: 60%;
    }
    
    .itemname {
        padding: 0.63em 0 0.63em 1em;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-left: inherit;
    }
    
    .single {
        background-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    }
    
    #link {
        color: rgb(19, 206, 200);
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
/*---------------BOTTOM------------*/
    #bottom {
        height: 12.5%;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(62,62,62,1) 2%,rgba(50,50,50,1) 50%,rgba(37,37,37,1) 100%);
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        box-shadow:  0px -2px 27px 0px black;
    }
  li.single {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}  
  
    #dropdown {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        margin: 2.5% 0 0 29%;
        background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
        color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    }
    
    #optionone {
        background-color: aqua;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <main>
        <section class="section" id="top">
            <h4>Contacts</h4>
        </section>
        
         <section class="section" id="mid">
             <ul id="contacts"></ul>
             <ul id="contactinfo"></ul>
        </section>
        
        <section class="section" id="bottom">
            <select id="dropdown">
                <option value="email">Email</option>
                <option value="number">Phone Number</option>
            </select>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `top` and `right` position values of the clicked element to the popup div so that it will get displayed on the right of clicked name.

```
    $('.itemname').on('click', function(event) {
      for (i in contactarray)
            if ($(event.target).html() === contactarray[i].name) {  

               $('.single').offset(this);

               $(".itemname").css("background-color", "inherit");
               $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(79,79,79");

               contactid = i
               $('#contactinfo').empty();
               //set top and left position of popup
               var offset = $(this).offset();           
               $("#contactinfo").css( {position:"absolute", top:offset.top,
                left: offset.right});
                displaysingle(contactid);
           }
   });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8pbLvtjf/5/)**

Comment: Hey thanks, this works but the layout overlaps and the width becomes really big on my screen, also when i switch options the layout is ruined, would it be better to use a separate div for the box instead of changing the existing list?

Comment: You can use `width:auto;` for #contactinfo css class or you can use box instead;